# How should I name this collection class?

Tags: naming-conventions, smalltalk

Imagine a subclass of `Collection` that knows a `select` block and a `collect` block. An instance of this class wraps another `collection` and dynamically applies to it these blocks. So, for instance, `#do:` is implemented as

```
do: aBlock
    collection
        select: [:element | select value: element]
        thenDo: [:element | | v |
            v := collect value: element.
            aBlock value: v]]
```

So, the question is how should I name this class? I've called it `WrappedCollection` but this name is ambiguous and, besides, this thing must already exist and have a name.

By the way, this is very similar to [Subclassing Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29320673/4081336), except that mine is not a `Stream`.

Comment: How about TransformedSelection

Comment: @LynHeadley, thanks for the hint, which is good. I've put it in my list.

Comment: @LynHeadley why don't you make that an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've finally decided to use `DerivedCollection`. Given that these objects represent collections obtained from other sources, much as mathematical sets can be defined by *intention* rather than *extension*, we picked a name that doesn't reveal their internal representation.

BTW, `DerivedCollection`s are specially useful for filtering (`#select:`) and transforming (`#collect:`) large amounts of data which we represent with instances of `StoredArray`, a kind of `Array` that stores its elements on disk.

Answer (score 1):

The `select` and `collect` blocks sound to me like condition criteria. So maybe you could name the class `ConditionalCollection`, implying that the collection changes in response to the conditions that are being applied.

And another idea I just had: `FilteredCollection`.

Comment: The first name that came to my mind was FilteredCollection as well.